# htaccess : How to replace string with special character?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect the URL :

```
https://www.example.com/blablabla,?trx_id=TX-23
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/blablabla,TX-23
```

Basically, I would like to remove the string : **?trx_id=**

I tried the following but it it's not working. It's seems like it's related to special characters

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)?trx_id=(.+)$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/998662/htaccess-how-to-replace-string-with-special-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because when the request is parsed by apache, it's split in several parts : host, port, path and query string. The directive RewriteRule matches against the url path which is : `blabla,` in your example, while the parameters are put in the query string `trx_id=TX-23` (question mark removed).
To match against the query string, you have to use a condition, like this.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^trx_id=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /$1%1 [R=301,QSD,L]
```

The condition only affects its following rule. Back references such as $N refer to the rule pattern, and %N refer to the condition pattern.

Also note the QSD flag to discard the initial query string, otherwise it would be kept in the rewritten request (at least in apache 2.4, note sure for apache 2.2).

Comment: For the external redirect to be valid, you will need to include a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (since the `$1` backreference does not contain this slash prefix in `.htaccess`). (Or be reliant on the `RewriteBase` - but this is not stated here.)

Comment: @MrWhite you are right, i have updated my answser, thank you :)